# Restructure Language Prefix example.com/ca-fr

Tags: 8, i18n-l10n, path-aliases

I created new Language method in Drupal 8, I need url example: example.com/en-fr, The first part of URL is a country code and the second is a language code.
Language switcher should give possibility to change country and language

Comment: A little more information would be helpful. What exactly did you do already? What is the specific problem you can't solve on your own?

Comment: I need to make a function for the method that will add the language code to the prefix in the url address, but Country list is stored as taxonomy terms with the country code field. If the language or the country is not found, then go back to 404 page. Functionality and vocabulary should be provided within module.

Answer (score 1):

Drupal doesn't support "country" selection in the language switcher, but you can easily add this yourself.

When you add languages (`/admin/config/regional/language/add`), choose "Custom" and then set the language code to whatever you want and then add the country to the name.

By default, custom languages will all be based off the site's default language (usually English).

If you want to base them off a different language, you will have to import translations for that language after adding the language.

Comment: You can show me any code example? Thanks.

Comment: @Taras You don't need to code; you can configure this from the UI as I described in my answer.

Comment: I need to make a function for the method that will add the language code to the prefix in the url address, but Country list is stored as taxonomy terms with the country code field. If the language or the country is not found, then go back to 404 page. Functionality and vocabulary should be provided within module.

Comment: @Taras This is highly specific to your particular use case and something you need to code yourself.